# Safari do not print Check Form properly where as Chrome does

Tags: pdf, safari, adobe, acumatica

When I print any Check Form, it opens as a PDF in the browser. It prints OK from Chrome but when I print it using Safari on MAC, it prints the same Check Form into two pages.

However, when I select the PDF or click on Check Form PDF and then print the Check Form using Safari, then it prints on single page, same like it prints from Chrome.

Any idea if there is any settings needs to be done in Safari for printing. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For printing always use PDF format if precise format matching is required:
[image]

On the workstation where it prints correctly, open the PDF and go into the print page setup then take note of all page settings, paper size, margins etc.. ask your technician to access page setup if you can't:
[image]

Be wary of any settings in page setup that attempts to resize the PDF before sending it to the printer:
[image]

Configure page setup (sometimes called print option) on Safari browser and macOS to match those that print successfully.

Links below are good starting points but actual configuration is dependent on OS and browser version. It's also out of scope of StackOverflow because it isn't a programming question. If you need help on configuring printers in Safari/MacOS and don't have a technician to do it, it would be better you ask on another stackexchange site, perhaps SuperUser would be the most appropriate:
https://support.apple.com/kb/ph25622?locale=en_US

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21472?locale=en_US